# store pointer to use for event listener registration

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a c++ (c++11) library I'm writing (an OpenGL graphics engine).

My question revolves around good programming techniques for registering an event listener.

I have class relationships like so:

`Program` --has--> `SceneManager` --has--> `ShaderManager` --has-->* `Shader`

The `Shader` class allows other objects to register themselves as a `ShaderBindListener`, which means that whenever the shader has it's `bind()` method called, it will notify any listeners.

The `ShaderManager` Class is the one that an outside library has access to, and from which they can create new `Shader` objects.

Now, I want each `Shader` object to have the `Program` object as a `ShaderBindListener`, so that when a `Shader` is bound, the `Program` object is notified and can pass matrix data, etc to the `Shader` on the GPU.

My initial solution was to have the `Program` object pass a pointer to itself to the `SceneManager`, which passes the pointer to the `ShaderManager`, which then stores it.  Whenever a new `Shader` is then created, the `ShaderManager` adds the `Program` as a listener.

This works just fine - but it seems - I don't know, a bit wrong in terms of design.

Maybe I'm just being pedantic - but does this seem like good design to you guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options, the pros and cons for which are often debatable and depends on your style.

**Singleton**

If a process will only ever have one instance of `Program`, then you could make `Program` a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This way, you don't need to pass the pointers around.

**An intermediate object**

Instead of passing the `this` pointer through, you could have it pass through an object which encapsulates `Program` and manages the event handling of it. That way, the other classes don't need to know about `Program`, they just need the interface for the event class.

In fact, if you aren't averse to using [Boost](http://boost.org), then they have just what you're looking for: the [Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/signals2.html) library.

Comment: Thanks @anthony.  Never heard of Boost Signals before, I'll check it out.  I was originally using singleton objects, but I've recently been readying about how they are the spawn of all evil, so I've been trying to refactor away from them.